# masm32 ReadFile Function x86 -Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, command-line, x86, masm32

I've been trying to read the string written inside a .txt file and print it out on the console. But it seems I'm not doing it right. Can someone review my codes and tell me what's wrong? Thanks!

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
  txtFilter db "*.txt",0

  txtFD WIN32_FIND_DATA <>
  txtHandle HANDLE ?
  fHandle HANDLE ?

  bufferLength db ?
  buffer db 5000 dup(?)
  lnt db "1024",0

  okay db "Okay!",0
  dokay db "Dokay!",0

.code
start:
  push offset txtFD
  push offset txtFilter
  call FindFirstFile

  mov txtHandle, eax

  push offset txtFD.cFileName
  call StdOut

  push 0
  push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
  push OPEN_EXISTING
  push 0
  push 0
  push FILE_APPEND_DATA
  push offset txtFD.cFileName
  call CreateFile

  .if eax == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    jmp _error
  .else
    mov fHandle, eax
  .endif

  push 0
  push offset bufferLength
  push offset lnt
  push offset buffer
  push fHandle
  call ReadFile

  jmp _next

_error:
  push offset dokay
  call StdOut
  jmp _next

_okay:
  push offset okay
  call StdOut

_next:
  push offset buffer
  call StdOut

  push fHandle
  call CloseHandle

  push txtHandle
  call FindClose

  push 0
  call ExitProcess

end start
```

The code can't seem to read what is inside my txt file. However I can successfully search my txt file and perform the function CreateFile

Comment: When you call ReadFile you are pushing `offset lnt` rather than just `lnt`.  The `nNumberOfBytesToRead` argument is passed by value, not by address.

Comment: also I doubt you have to provide the length `lnt` as ascii string. i would try ' lnt dd 1024' instead

Answer (score 1):

Four issues:

- `bufferLength db ?` reserves only one byte. `ReadFile` will store there a DWORD and overwrite three bytes of `buffer`. If there is a NULL, `StdOut` will stop the output. Change the definition to `bufferLength dd ?`
- `lnt db "1024",0` is a string. `ReadFile` expects a DWORD value. Change it to `lnt dd 1024`.
- `push FILE_APPEND_DATA` creates a handle only for writing. Change it to `push GENERIC_READ`.
- `push offset lnt` passes a pointer. However, `ReadFile` expects a DWORD value. Change it to `push lnt`.

Like that:

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
    txtFilter db "*.txt",0

    txtFD WIN32_FIND_DATA <>
    txtHandle HANDLE ?
    fHandle HANDLE ?

;   bufferLength db ?
    bufferLength dd ?
    buffer db 5000 dup(?)
;   lnt db "1024",0
    lnt dd 1024

    okay db "Okay!",0
    dokay db "Dokay!",0

.code
start:
    push offset txtFD
    push offset txtFilter
    call FindFirstFile

    mov txtHandle, eax

    push offset txtFD.cFileName
    call StdOut

    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx
    push 0                          ; HANDLE    hTemplateFile
    push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL      ; DWORD     dwFlagsAndAttributes
    push OPEN_EXISTING              ; DWORD     dwCreationDisposition
    push 0                          ; LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes
    push 0                          ; DWORD     dwShareMode
;   push FILE_APPEND_DATA           ; DWORD     dwDesiredAccess
    push GENERIC_READ               ; DWORD     dwDesiredAccess
    push offset txtFD.cFileName     ; LPCTSTR   lpFileName,
    call CreateFile

    .if eax == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        jmp _error
    .else
        mov fHandle, eax
    .endif

    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx
    push 0                          ; LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    push offset bufferLength        ; LPDWORD   lpNumberOfBytesRead
;   push offset lnt                 ; DWORD     nNumberOfBytesToRead
    push lnt                        ; DWORD     nNumberOfBytesToRead
    push offset buffer              ; LPVOID    lpBuffer
    push fHandle                    ; HANDLE    hFile
    call ReadFile

    jmp _next

_error:
    push offset dokay
    call StdOut
    jmp _next

_okay:
    push offset okay
    call StdOut

_next:
    push offset buffer
    call StdOut

    push fHandle
    call CloseHandle

    push txtHandle
    call FindClose

    push 0
    call ExitProcess

end st
```